# Не получается использовать PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Код написал так:

```
<?php

//namespace App;
//require_once ('PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php');
//require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

class TestSolution extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testHasEqualOnesCount()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(4, Calc/add(2, 2));
    }
}
```

Запускаю и получаю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя PHPUnit у меня установлен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Комментарии в коде - это то как я пробовал устранить проблему. Раскомменчиваю каждую из этих строк по отдельности и в любых комбинациях ошибку не устранил.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить файл напрямую как PHP-executable, а хотите, очевидно, скормить PHPUnit. Поэтому запуск, очевидно, должен выглядеть так:

```
phpunit TestSolution.php
```

а не

```
php TestSolution.php
```

Comment: command not found: phpunit

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров у вас на втором скрине он нормально вызывается. У вас мог измениться $PATH?

Comment: я $PATH не менял. Когда устанавливал phpunit прописывал $PATH, что бы его ото всюду можно было вызывать. Я кажется понял в чем дело. Извиняюсь что сразу не написал, не думал что это повлияет. Я запускал тесты через Babun. А проверял наличие phpunit через cmd. Через cmd тесты запустились. А через Babun почему-то не хотят

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров если честно, не имел дело с babun, но судя по харкактеру ошибки, проблема все равно в том, что в PATH (при выполнении в babun) не указан путь к папке с PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Используй:

`phpunit TestSolution.php`

phpunit документация на русском языке:

[PHPUnit документация на русском](http://itfor.xyz/category/develop/phpunit-na-russkom/)